# Multiple imputation using Amelia() in R

Tags: r

Multiple Imputation (MI) has 3 steps.

- Step1. Impute
- Step2. Analysis
- Step3. Combine (Pooling)

I implemented this code using the `Amelia` package in R.

```
> th.out <-amelia(th, m=5, ts="CTIME", cs="ID")   
 #'th' is a dataset related to temperature and humidity.
```

The result of `amelia()` is 5 imputed data sets. `(th.out$imputations[1], th.out$imputations[2] .... th.out$imputations[5])`.

It seems `amelia()`  implements only step1 (impute).  How can I do Step 2 (analysis) and Step 3 (combine)? Can you recommend some functions or packages to perform the remaining two steps?

Comment: I realize that English is not everyone's native tongue, but in a coding forum, that problem is best addressed by providing coded examples. The responsibility for "more detail" begins with the person asking hte question.

Comment: How is question different to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725026/i-have-some-questions-about-amelia-in-r-can-sombody-help-me)?

Comment: I misunderstood that question was too many. I'll update question with source code. sorry